# Bride Groom Problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamical-systems, puzzle

Let's consider a system of $n$ men and women. Each woman is paired with one man (there are only pairings between a woman and a man in this system). There are $n!$ possible distinct pairings. I refer to a pairing as the *state* of the system. Every man and every woman has a preference list for their potential partners. It is not possible that a woman is equally attracted to two men and it is also impossible that a man is equally attracted to two women.

When a woman is higher on the preference list of a man than his current partner and at the same time this man is higher on the preference list than her current partner they will leave their current partners and form a new pair. Their former partners also form a new pair (although they potentially will be less satisfied with their new partner than before the split). In the following I will refer to such a change in the state of the system as an *allowed move*. I define a state in which no moves are possible as *stable*.

I have the following questions about this system:

1. When I start with a state there might be a number of allowed moves (according to the above definition). Will the system always end up in a stable state, no matter in which order I carry out these moves? If no, will it at least end up in a stable state if I carry out the moves randomly?
2. If the answer to the first question is no, is there at least always a stable state?
3. If there is always a stable state, does it have to be unique? If no, can I evolve into different stable states depending on the order in which I carry out the allowed moves starting from the same initial state?

Comment: This was the subject of a recent [Numberphile video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Qcv1IqHWAzg).

Comment: I was not aware of this, thank you very much for the link. However I think it doesn't answer all of my questions but only answers question 2 with a yes.